# Can't read input value on click on a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to implement login form and i am using some template that i have found on the net. I am adding it to my page dynamically using append() function. Login form has following structure:

```
<div class="logmod__container">
<ul class="logmod__tabs">
    <li data-tabtar="lgm-2" class="current"><a href="#">Login</a></li>
    <li data-tabtar="lgm-1"><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="logmod__tab-wrapper">
    <div class="logmod__tab lgm-1">
        <div class="logmod__heading">
            <span class="logmod__heading-subtitle">Enter your personal details <strong>to create an acount</strong></span>
        </div>
        <div class="logmod__form">
            <form accept-charset="utf-8" action="#" class="simform">
                <div class="sminputs">
                    <div class="input full">
                        <label class="string optional" for="user-name">Email*</label>
                        <input class="string optional" maxlength="255" id="user-email" placeholder="Email" type="text" size="50">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="sminputs">
                    <div class="input string optional">
                        <label class="string optional" for="user-pw">Password *</label>
                        <input class="string optional" maxlength="255" id="user-pw" placeholder="Password" type="text" size="50">
                    </div>
                    <div class="input string optional">
                        <label class="string optional" for="user-pw-repeat">Repeat password *</label>
                        <input class="string optional" maxlength="255" id="user-pw-repeat" placeholder="Repeat password" type="text" size="50">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="simform__actions">
                    <input class="sumbit" name="commit" type="button" value="Create Account">
                    <span class="simform__actions-sidetext">By creating an account you agree to our <a class="special" href="#" target="_blank" role="link">Terms &amp; Privacy</a></span>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="logmod__alter">
            <div class="logmod__alter-container">
                <a href="#" class="connect facebook">
                    <div class="connect__icon">
                        <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="connect__context">
                        <span>Create an account with <strong>Facebook</strong></span>
                    </div>
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="connect googleplus">
                    <div class="connect__icon">
                        <i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="connect__context">
                        <span>Create an account with <strong>Google+</strong></span>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="logmod__tab lgm-2 show">
        <div class="logmod__heading">
            <span class="logmod__heading-subtitle">Enter your email and password <strong>to sign in</strong></span>
        </div>
        <div class="logmod__form">
            <form accept-charset="utf-8" action="#" class="simform">
                <div class="sminputs">
                    <div class="input full">
                        <label class="string optional" for="user-name">Email*</label>
                        <input class="string optional" maxlength="255" id="user-email" placeholder="Email" type="text" size="50">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="sminputs">
                    <div class="input full">
                        <label class="string optional" for="user-pw">Password *</label>
                        <input class="string optional" maxlength="255" id="user-pw" placeholder="Password" type="password" size="50">
                        <span class="hide-password">Show</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="simform__actions">
                    <input class="sumbit" name="commit" type="button" value="Log In">
                    <span class="simform__actions-sidetext">
                        <a class="special" role="link" href="#">Forgot your password?<br>Click here</a>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="logmod__alter">
            <div class="logmod__alter-container">
                <a href="#" class="connect facebook">
                    <div class="connect__icon">
                        <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="connect__context">
                        <span>Sign in with <strong>Facebook</strong></span>
                    </div>
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="connect googleplus">
                    <div class="connect__icon">
                        <i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="connect__context">
                        <span>Sign in with <strong>Google+</strong></span>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to read data from inputs with **user-email** and **user-pw** ids on click on submit button. I have tried things like:

```
var email = document.getElementById('user-email');
var val = email.value;
```

or

```
var email = $('#user-email').val();
```

or

```
var email = $('#user-email').text();
```

or

```
var email = $('#user-email').attr("value");
```

to read email that i entered to input field, but all of these returns me only "".
My last try was to add **onfocusout** handler and there to read values and store them into global variables, before clicking on button, but neither that worked.

Comment: You have duplicate ids.  You have 2 inputs with id 'user-email' and 2 inputs with id 'user-pw'  ID's must be unique.  It's getting the value from the last ones on the page, which is probably not the ones you're entering values into.

Comment: Duplicate ids are not the problem. In fact i resolved this and your comment was trigger of my solution. Thank you. I have class **shown** that is added to tab that is clicked and i selected input using that class and id.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to retrieve values on page-load , you'll have blank values. But if you are trying to retrieve values on some event, such as when the Create Account button is clicked, you should be able to see the email value displayed.
Check my snippet below :(And I've changed your duplicate input ids for email to `user-email` and `user-email2`)

**Snippet :**

```js
$('#create').click(function() {
  var email = $('#user-email').val();
  console.log(email);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="logmod__container">
  <ul class="logmod__tabs">
    <li data-tabtar="lgm-2" class="current"><a href="#">Login</a>
    </li>
    <li data-tabtar="lgm-1"><a href="#">Sign Up</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="logmod__tab-wrapper">
    <div class="logmod__tab lgm-1">
      <div class="logmod__heading">
        <span class="logmod__heading-subtitle">Enter your personal details <strong>to create an acount</strong></span>
      </div>
      <div class="logmod__form">
        <form accept-charset="utf-8" action="#" class="simform">
          <div class="sminputs">
            <div class="input full">
              <label class="string optional" for="user-name">Email*</label>
              <input class="string optional" maxlength="255" id="user-email" placeholder="Email" type="text" size="50">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="sminputs">
            <div class="input string optional">
              <label class="string optional" for="user-pw">Password *</label>
              <input class="string optional" maxlength="255" id="user-pw" placeholder="Password" type="text" size="50">
            </div>
            <div class="input string optional">
              <label class="string optional" for="user-pw-repeat">Repeat password *</label>
              <input class="string optional" maxlength="255" id="user-pw-repeat" placeholder="Repeat password" type="text" size="50">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="simform__actions">
            <input class="sumbit" name="commit" type="button" value="Create Account" id="create">
            <span class="simform__actions-sidetext">By creating an account you agree to our <a class="special" href="#" target="_blank" role="link">Terms &amp; Privacy</a></span>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="logmod__alter">
        <div class="logmod__alter-container">
          <a href="#" class="connect facebook">
            <div class="connect__icon">
              <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="connect__context">
              <span>Create an account with <strong>Facebook</strong></span>
            </div>
          </a>
          <a href="#" class="connect googleplus">
            <div class="connect__icon">
              <i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="connect__context">
              <span>Create an account with <strong>Google+</strong></span>
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="logmod__tab lgm-2 show">
      <div class="logmod__heading">
        <span class="logmod__heading-subtitle">Enter your email and password <strong>to sign in</strong></span>
      </div>
      <div class="logmod__form">
        <form accept-charset="utf-8" action="#" class="simform">
          <div class="sminputs">
            <div class="input full">
              <label class="string optional" for="user-name">Email*</label>
              <input class="string optional" maxlength="255" id="user-email2" placeholder="Email" type="text" size="50">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="sminputs">
            <div class="input full">
              <label class="string optional" for="user-pw">Password *</label>
              <input class="string optional" maxlength="255" id="user-pw" placeholder="Password" type="password" size="50">
              <span class="hide-password">Show</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="simform__actions">
            <input class="sumbit" name="commit" type="button" value="Log In">
            <span class="simform__actions-sidetext">
                        <a class="special" role="link" href="#">Forgot your password?<br>Click here</a>
                    </span>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="logmod__alter">
        <div class="logmod__alter-container">
          <a href="#" class="connect facebook">
            <div class="connect__icon">
              <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="connect__context">
              <span>Sign in with <strong>Facebook</strong></span>
            </div>
          </a>
          <a href="#" class="connect googleplus">
            <div class="connect__icon">
              <i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="connect__context">
              <span>Sign in with <strong>Google+</strong></span>
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have duplicate ids. You have 2 inputs with id 'user-email' and 2 inputs with id 'user-pw' ID's must be unique. It's getting the value from the last ones on the page, which is probably not the ones you're entering values into